# Putting the Z-Coordinate in the Highcharts Tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have three graphs. All three graphs have the same x axis values (category), different y-values, and the same z-value (date). The graphs have synced tooltips when you hover over a point. I want to be able to populate the tooltip with the z-coordinate for each point. I **do not** want to plot the z coordinate... just have it show in the tooltip. I am not sure how to do this because there are more multiple graphs with synced tooltips.

I made a basic example to show how to put the z-value (date) in a tooltip for one graph. https://codepen.io/austeng/pen/ZEGxWyK

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return 'x: ' + this.x + ', y: ' + this.y + ', z: ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b/%e/%Y',
          new Date(this.point.z));
      }
    },
  xAxis:{
    type: 'category'
  },
    series: [{
      data: [{
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          z: 1564358400000
        },
        {
          x: 1,
          y: 5,
          z: 1564531200000
        },
        {
          x: 2,
          y: 2,
          z: 1564963200000
        }
      ]
    }]
  });
```

This is my codepen for the three graphs: https://codepen.io/austeng/pen/gOppRWY

Any help on how to extend my example for one graph to my current code of three graphs w/sync tooltip would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it will be better to achieve it in a different way.

1. Create some global function, let's say **setTooltip** which will take a point as a parameter.
2. For each chart config set the **tooltip.pointFormatter** callback which returns above function.

   ```
   tooltip: {
      pointFormatter() {
        let point = this;

        return setTooltip(point)
       }
   },
   ```
3. Use the **keys** feature to get the z value in the point object.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.keys

Final output: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sjv18rbn/